# Java Object as a monitor clarification

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, monitor

I used following resources to get to a summary of Java monitors,

> http://www.informit.com/store/concurrent-programming-in-java-design-principles-and-9780201310092
>
> http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch.html

And following is the summary from my understanding in the context of Java ,

> Monitor is an object that is awarded about Threads. That   >means when saying in Java that all objects are monitors >that means each object has the trait of thread awareness.
>
> Thread is an active object . And other objects are passive >but are aware about threads .Hence monitors! In other >words passive objects have  been smartened.
>
> Why call "monitor" , because it monitors itself ! From what ? >From active objects i.e  Threads
>
> What awareness a monitor has?
>
> a)It knows what thread currently access it.{owner}
>
> b)It knows what threads are waiting on it till a special condition >   is met.{wait set}
>
> c)It knows who are in the queue to enter to it{entry
>    set}
>
> So how could a thread become an objects owner , it has to >acquire that object's lock !

---

> 1 Object IS a lock or HAS a lock ?
>
> 2 Above a,b,c are part of the state of an object or keep  tracked  by the JVM ( keep a record and associate it to the Object ID etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Each object in Java *has* a monitor associated with it. A monitor is a construct that is essentially equivalent to a reentrant lock; the same thread can enter a monitor multiple times, and the number of entries is counted and matched against the exits.

Your conclusions about "active" and "passive" objects don't make much sense. (I'm not saying they're *wrong*; I'm saying I can't understand what you're trying to say.)

[The semantics of monitors in the JVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.monitorenter) is well-defined, but the implementation is not, and there are a number of ways that the monitor could be implemented. All of the items in your a/b/c are kept track of by the JVM in some way that the JVM author decides. Since most objects' monitors are never used, one strategy would be to have a table of monitors, separate from the heap, that contained a `struct` with the object's JVM ID, the thread currently inside the monitor, and the entry count.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Java parlance, people tend to say that each object *has* a monitor. The statement `synchronized( anObject )` means `acquire anObject's monitor`.
2. An object doesn't "know" about the threads that currently access it. At a point in time, an object might be active in multiple threads.

   From the *language point of view*, there is no way to list the threads that currently use an object (a), nor to list the threads that wait on it (b and c).

   From the *JVM point of view*, the JVM must internally be able to do b and c, but not really a.